# How to find the deepest path that exists in Bash

Tags: bash

When I get an error like:

```
$ ls /var/django-projects/daks/public/media/uploads/bandsaws/sneaks.jpg
ls: /var/django-projects/daks/public/media/uploads/bandsaws/sneaks.jpg: No such file or directory
```

I'd like to be able to ask `what-is-the-deepest-path-that-does-exists` and get back, say:

```
/var/django-projects/daks/public/media/
```

I think it could be done with a loop that added `../` on each iteration and quitted when a path that exists was found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may well find `dirname` useful.  Something such as:

```
f=/var/django-projects/daks/public/media/uploads/bandsaws/sneaks.jpg

until [ -e "$f" ]; do f=$(dirname "$f"); done

echo $f
```

should give you `/var/django-projects/daks/public/media/`

Comment: Using `g="${f%/*}; if [ "$f" = "$g" ]; then f=.; else f="$g"; fi` duplicates the functionality of `dirname` without both depending on an external command and needing to spawn a separate process for something a POSIX shell can do natively.  Otherwise +1

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
FILE="/var/django-projects/daks/public/media/uploads/bandsaws/sneaks.jpg"
while true; do [ -e "$FILE" ] && break || FILE=$(dirname "$FILE"); done; echo $FILE
```

Comment: You could write `while ! [ -e "$FILE" ]; do FILE=$(dirname "$FILE"); done`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
function firstValidParent () { 
    d="$1"
    [ -e "${d}" ] && echo $d || firstValidParent "${d%/*}"
}
```

Comment: That last parameter expansion doesn't work.  Try `"${d%/*}"`.  Don't forget to quote.

Comment: Meanwhile, I reworked the quoting with sed. Will test your suggestion.